# How can i use SharedPreferences information register activity to login activity?

Tags: android, android-studio

My project has 3 activities, login, register, and profile...so I want to take register information to login by SharedPreferences..how can I do this?

Comment: https://www.journaldev.com/9412/android-shared-preferences-example-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

Save data to sharedpreferences

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)
                    .edit()
                    .putString("identifier", data)
                    .apply();
```

To retrieve data

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).getString("identifier", "default_value");
```

Note that you can store and retrieve different data types, I showed an example using String, but int, double and others work similarly.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this class for saving you preference for entire app,

```
public class AppSharedPreferences {
public static final String TAG = "AppSharedPreferences";
private static SharedPreferences sharedPref;

private String demo_string = "demo string's key"

public AppSharedPreferences() {

}

public static void init(Context context)
{
    if(sharedPref == null)
        sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences(
            context.getPackageName(), Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
}

public static void setDemoString(String demoString) {
    Editor prefs = sharedPref.edit();
    prefs.putString(demo_string, demoString);
    prefs.apply();
}

public static String getDemoString() {
    return sharedPref.getString(demo_string, "");
}}
```

Put this wherever u want to use shared prefs:

```
AppSharedPreferences.init(this);
```

You can exchange this for activity or context, depending on where you use the code.

To set value in preference, use this code:

```
AppSharedPreferences.setDemoString("Some Text");
```

To get the value from preference:

```
String text = AppSharedPreferences.getDemoString();
```